# Extending IPython task scheduler for custom load balancing

Tags: python, ipython, distributed-computing, ipython-parallel

I want to be able to implement my own load-calculating scheme for IPython parallel's LoadBalancedView, which uses a TaskScheduler.

I'm piecing through the source, and this looks like a likely candidate:

https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/IPython/parallel/controller/scheduler.py#L604

I don't think my problem is as simple as defining a different scheme such as LRU [here](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/IPython/parallel/controller/scheduler.py#L68) because I want to change the load value per job based on the type of job. (I may also need to extend Job here too to add some metadata about the job type in order to calculate load).

Any idea how I can best do this? I'm new to iPython.